# WSDL one-way operation and HTTP statuses

Tags: soap, wsdl, http-status-codes

Context first - think one-way WSDL operation (aka fire and forget, input only):

http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_one-way

Now, is it safe to assume that request is successful when server returns 202 Accepted http status code? Is it standardized somewhere? Link to some specifications would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP 1.2 Part 2 (Adjuncts) describes the details of SOAP 1.2's HTTP binding. In [1] it is stated:

> 202   OK
>
> The request has been accepted, but either (a) no response envelope is provided or (b) an envelope representing information related to the request is provided -- such envelopes SHOULD be processed using the SOAP Processing model (see SOAP 1.2 Part 1, section SOAP Processing Model).

For a one-way operation, (a) is the case.

[1] http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part2/#http-reqbindwaitstate